# Delphi DBgrid Expand/Collapse

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, adodb, dbgrid

I'm trying to implement an **expand/collapse** option in the Delphi **DBGrid**.
Sadly it is not a default supported option. The data used for display is comming from an **ADOStoredProcedure**.

The function has to be made for the DBGrid, using a **alternative component lib** **is not an option**. The SMDBGrid is avalible though (also does not support e/c)

Searching Google has not given me anything usefull yet. I'm wondering if anyone here has tackled this problem or an idea of how to go at this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Virtual Treeview](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview). In the [Downloads](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/all-downloads) section you can find [demo apps](http://www.soft-gems.net/supplement/download.php?ID=33), [Virtual Treeview contributions](http://www.soft-gems.net/supplement/download.php?ID=50), [add ons](http://www.soft-gems.net/supplement/download.php?ID=31) and [Virtual Treeview and databases](http://www.soft-gems.net/supplement/download.php?ID=60) including DB-aware versions and examples.

Comment: @Abelisto I've eddited the question, using an alternative component is not an option sadly. I'm looking for a way to implement the function in the DBGrid

Comment: So you have to deal with DataSet (ADOStoredProcedure), not with DBGrid. Handle some event on DBGrid (OnDblClick for example) and filter/unfilter the records in DataSet.

Comment: I'm  currently trying to fix this by using a click on the indicator (still in progress) however is there a way to show if an row is expanded/collapsed

Comment: Look at `OnDrawXXX` events on the DBGrid. Also you can create calculated field (`FieldKind := fkInternalCalc`) in the DataSet using Fields Editor. `fkInternalCalc` is important because it allows not only calculate value on another fields but also allows to edit and store the value.

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks looks usefull, I'll look in to it

Comment: You want a visual effect like DevExpress Quantum Grid? If yes, i think you probably need to go for a 3tdParty component. Its too much time and pain to implement master-detail on dbgrid. And why using another compoonent is not an option? I think doing this on TDBGrid is not an option.

Comment: @oPsDCadarn Effects are not needed. I almost got it working now by creating an onDBLClick for the indicator and using filters

Comment: You can do it by using Master-Detail DataSets if you don't need the effects ("+" and identation as well as the records above position calculation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some time but I managed to create te functionality for the DBGrid using a dynamic filter on the dataset. I'll post the code for someone who would need this functionality.

**Class to store expanded items**

```
type
  //Store ID's used to keep expanded items
  TPlanningFilterItem = class(TObject)
    public
      Sublevel, ProjectID, OnderdeelID, MedewerkerID: integer;
  end;
```

**Capture indicator click**

```
  procedure TFPlanningOverzicht.GridPlanningDblClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    P: TPoint;
    C: TGridCoord;
  begin
    GetCursorPos(P);
    P := (Sender as TCustomGrid).ScreenToClient(P);
    C := (Sender as TCustomGrid).MouseCoord(P.X, P.Y);

    //Only capture indicator row X = 0
    //Ignore title indicator Y > 1
    if (C.X = 0) AND (C.Y > 0) then
      DatasetFilterToevoegenVerwijderen;
      FilterDataSet;
    begin
    end;
  end;
```

**Add or remove filter**

```
  procedure TFPlanningOverzicht.DatasetFilterToevoegenVerwijderen;
  var
    newFilterItem: TPlanningFilterItem;
    tmp: TPlanningFilterItem;
    I: Integer;
  begin
      newFilterItem := TPlanningFilterItem.Create;
      newFilterItem.Sublevel := DPlanning.PlanningOverzicht.FieldByName('SUBLEVEL').AsInteger;
      newFilterItem.ProjectID := DPlanning.PlanningOverzicht.FieldByName('ProjectID').AsInteger;
      newFilterItem.OnderdeelID := DPlanning.PlanningOverzicht.FieldByName('OnderdeelID').AsInteger;
      newFilterItem.MedewerkerID := DPlanning.PlanningOverzicht.FieldByName('MedewerkerID').AsInteger;

      //Ignore expand when deepest lvl reached
      if newFilterItem.Sublevel > 2 then
        Exit;

      for I := 0 to GridFilterItems.Count - 1 do
      begin
        //Compare to existing
        tmp := GridFilterItems.Items[I];
        if (tmp.Sublevel = newFilterItem.Sublevel) AND
            (tmp.ProjectID = newFilterItem.ProjectID) AND
            (tmp.OnderdeelID = newFilterItem.OnderdeelID) AND
            (tmp.MedewerkerID = newFilterItem.MedewerkerID)
        then
        begin
          //If item currently expanded collapse and exit
          GridFilterItems.Delete(I);
          Exit;
        end;
      end;

      //Item not yet expanded, so expand
      GridFilterItems.Add(newFilterItem);
  end;
```

**Applying the filter**

```
  procedure TFPlanningOverzicht.FilterDataSet;
  var
    I: integer;
    tmp: TPlanningFilterItem;
    Filter: string;
    C: Integer;
  begin
    //Always show top level items
    Filter := '(SUBLEVEL = ''' + IntToStr(1) + ''' ) OR ';

    for I := 0 to GridFilterItems.Count - 1 do
    begin
      tmp := GridFilterItems[I];

      //Expand when 1st row selected (shoud be written to your case)
      if (tmp.Sublevel= 1) then
      begin
        Filter := Filter +
        '(MedewerkerID = ''' + IntToStr(tmp.MedewerkerID) + ''' AND ' +
        'SUBLEVEL = ''' + IntToStr(2) + ''' ) OR ';
      end
      else
      begin
        //Expands for the second level (shoud be written to your case)
        Filter := Filter +
        '(MedewerkerID = ''' + IntToStr(tmp.MedewerkerID) + ''' AND ' +
        'OnderdeelID = ''' + IntToStr(tmp.OnderdeelID) + ''' AND ' +
        'SUBLEVEL = ''' + IntToStr(3) + ''' ) OR ';
      end;
    end;

    //Remove last or
    Delete(Filter, Filter.Length - 2, 3);

    GridPlanning.DataSource.DataSet.Filter := Filter;
    GridPlanning.DataSource.DataSet.Filtered := True;
  end;
```

Hope this would be usefull to someone.